# When trying to open a fragment, this errors are showing

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm a pretty noob on android app dev. I'm trying to open create an ebook app. And the app is running. But when I'm trying to open the download fragment, this thing error is happening and the app crashes!
Here's the java code for the fragment activity - 
    package com.domain.app.Fragment;

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.loopj.android.http.*;

import com.domain.app.Activity.MainActivity;
import com.domain.app.Activity.Search;
import com.domain.app.Adapter.DownloadAdapter;
import com.domain.app.DataBase.DatabaseHandler;
import com.domain.app.Item.DownloadList;
import com.domain.app.R;
import com.domain.app.Util.Constant_Api;
import com.wang.avi.AVLoadingIndicatorView;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Queue;


public class DownloadFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private AVLoadingIndicatorView progressBar;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
    private DownloadAdapter downloadAdapter;
    public MenuItem searchItem;
    private List<File> inFiles;
    private List<DownloadList> downloadListsCompair;
    private String root;
    private DatabaseHandler db;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.category_fragment, container, false);

        MainActivity.toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.download));

        db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

        inFiles = new ArrayList<>();
        downloadListsCompair = new ArrayList<>();
        root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/appName/";

        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefresh_category_fragment);
        progressBar = (AVLoadingIndicatorView) view.findViewById(R.id.progressbar_category_fragment);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_category_fragment);

        progressBar.hide();

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setFocusable(false);

        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.toolbar);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                new Execute().execute();
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });

        new Execute().execute();

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);

        searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.ic_searchView);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener((new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), Search.class)
                        .putExtra("search", query));
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return true;
            }
        }));

        MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchItem,
                new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                        // Do something when collapsed
                        return true; // Return true to collapse action view
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                        // Do something when expanded
                        return true; // Return true to expand action view
                    }
                });

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // action with ID action_refresh was selected
            default:
                break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    class Execute extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog.show();
            progressDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.loading));
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            Constant_Api.downloadLists.clear();
            inFiles.clear();
            downloadListsCompair.clear();
            Constant_Api.db = new DatabaseHandler(getContext());
            Constant_Api.downloadLists = Constant_Api.db.getDownload();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            File file = new File(root);
            getListFiles(file);
            getDownloadLists(inFiles);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            downloadAdapter = new DownloadAdapter(getActivity(), downloadListsCompair);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(downloadAdapter);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            super.onPostExecute(s);
        }
    }

    private List<File> getListFiles(File parentDir) {
        // List<File> inFiles = new ArrayList<>();
        Queue<File> files = new LinkedList<>();
        files.addAll(Arrays.asList(parentDir.listFiles()));
        while (!files.isEmpty()) {
            File file = files.remove();
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                files.addAll(Arrays.asList(file.listFiles()));
            } else if (file.getName().endsWith(".epub") || file.getName().endsWith(".pdf")) {
                inFiles.add(file);
            }
        }
        return inFiles;
    }

    private List<DownloadList> getDownloadLists(List<File> list) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Constant_Api.downloadLists.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
                if (list.get(j).toString().contains(Constant_Api.downloadLists.get(i).getUrl())) {
                    downloadListsCompair.add(Constant_Api.downloadLists.get(i));
                    break;
                } else {
                    if (j == list.size() - 1) {
                        db.deletePdf(Constant_Api.downloadLists.get(i).getId());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return downloadListsCompair;
    }

}
```

And here is the error I'm seeing on Run window on Android Studio -

```
    V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
I/zygote: JIT allocated 56KB for compiled code of void android.view.View.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
                  Process: com.domain.app, PID: 12493
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:353)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
                      at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:3741)
                      at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:3728)
                      at com.domain.app.Fragment.DownloadFragment.getListFiles(DownloadFragment.java:181)
                      at com.domain.app.Fragment.DownloadFragment.access$500(DownloadFragment.java:43)
                      at com.domain.app.Fragment.DownloadFragment$Execute.doInBackground(DownloadFragment.java:164)
                      at com.domain.app.Fragment.DownloadFragment$Execute.doInBackground(DownloadFragment.java:146)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 10252
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 4589154
D/FA: Logging event (FE): adunit_exposure(_xu), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=am, ad_unit_id(_ai)=ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=751889283038278768, exposure_time(_xt)=9442}]
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
D/FA: Logging event (FE): ad_exposure(_xa), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=am, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=751889283038278768, exposure_time(_xt)=9442}]
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=10252, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=751889283038278768}]
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
      Not logging ad unit exposure. No active activity
      Not logging ad exposure. No active activity
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe62e4f20: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe624c000)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe62e4f20: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe624c000)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe62e4f20: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe624c000)
D/FA: Connected to remote service
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe62e4f20: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe624c000)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe62e4f20: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe624c000)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe62e4f20: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe624c000)
E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.domain.app.Activity.MainActivity has leaked window DecorView@2ec76c[] that was originally added here
                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:485)
                     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:346)
                     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
                     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:330)
                     at com.domain.app.Fragment.DownloadFragment$Execute.onPreExecute(DownloadFragment.java:150)
                     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:648)
                     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:595)
                     at com.domain.app.Fragment.DownloadFragment.onCreateView(DownloadFragment.java:91)
                     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2343)
                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1421)
                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1752)
                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1821)
                     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2595)
                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2382)
                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2337)
                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2244)
                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:702)
                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
I/Ads: Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
       Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
I/Ads: Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
       Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
```

Please help me to find the actual problem and what can be the solution of this errors! Thank in advance... :)

Comment: `parentDir.listFiles()` is likely returning null, meaning it's probably not a directory.

Comment: root is a directory declared here. so, can I use root.listFiles()? Tried that but not worked either... :(

Comment: What's at line 181, per the stacktrace?

Comment: files.addAll(Arrays.asList(parentDir.listFiles()));

Comment: Check if `parentDir.listFiles()` is null.

Comment: It's not null because inside `doInBackground()`, `File file = new File(root); getListFiles(file);` are listed. And the root also declared on top of the file, where it's pointed to a valid directory!

Comment: What do you mean by "`getListFiles(file);` are listed"? That's the method where the crash is.

Comment: Will you mind if I send you the project and you see it on the android studio?

Comment: Uh sure. Put it on GitHub.

Comment: Can I get your email, please? I can't put it on public repository now for some reason. But I can send you though! I don't have enough reputation point on here that's why can't send you on chat too! I think I'm not getting the issue. But you'll find in the shortest time I believe... :)

Comment: My email is on my GitHub profile, which you can find linked in my SO profile.

Comment: I've sent you the download link! :)

Comment: After updating the dependencies and fixing some problems in the libraries you have, I don't have any crash issues. I recommend you fix those issues. Also, AsyncTasks should be static. Everything you have in `onPreExecute()` can go in the Fragment itself before you execute the AsyncTask, and you can pass a callback to the AsyncTask to run what you need in `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: can you send me the exported zip, please? That will be so helpful as I don't know how to update those dependencies and what should I update! :)

Comment: @TheWanderer the problem still exists. When you run the app, skip the login activity, then open the menu drawer and tap on Download option to open download fragment. Then actually the problem occurs. Otherwise, everything else on the app is perfectly working!

Comment: I did that and it was fine. How many devices have you tested this on?

Comment: On emulator only. But let me test that on my real device!

Comment: Nope. Just tested on my android 8.0 device. But it keeps crashing on the same place. It only crashes when I try to open the Downloads option from the menu. On a note, on your version, I'm seeing the DownloadFragment.java is same as mine old one. I'm not seeing the updates you mentioned in your last comment. Maybe that's missing on my end and keeping the issue!

Comment: I just updated some dependencies in Gradle and code in those libraries you have included.

Comment: I'm running the project which you've sent me over email. But still getting those errors on the log! I'm getting fed up!